# My div block does not push the page content down and javascript is not closing the div block

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I'm trying to create a banner add block for donation. This div block should push the page content down. Also there is a close button to close the banner. However, the close button doesn't work. In the banner.js file I'm listening for a click and adding a banner-hide class to each div to close the banner.
Can someone help? I'm including the html css and javascript code blocks here.

html:

```
<div id="alert-banner" class="banner banner-top alert-primary" role="banner">
  <div class="p-4 align-self-end" style="max-width:30em">
    <h1 class="pb-4">Help us wake up to a 2020 that changes the way we see vision loss!</h1>
    <div class="text-center text-md-left"><a class="btn btn-donate text-center" style="min-width: 14em;" href="https://secure.everyaction.com/">Make a Donation</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

banner.js:

```
$(function() {
  var add - banner = $('#alert-banner');
  var btnClose = $('.banner-close');

  btnClose.addEventListener("click", function(closeEvt) {
    $(".banner").addClass("banner-hide");
    $(".p-4").addClass("banner-hide");
    $(".text-center").addClass("banner-hide");
  });
});
```

banner.css

```
.banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  max-height: 100px; /* set it at will according to your message's length 
  in small devices */
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  outline: none !important;
  display: block;
}

.banner * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner-bottom {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.banner-top {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 10px;
}

.banner-right {
   right: 10px;
  bottom: 10%;
  min-height: 10vh;
}

.banner-left {
  left: 10px;
  bottom:  10%;
  min-height: 10vh;
}

.alert-primary {
text-align: left;
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
white-space: normal;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
outline: none !important;
  color: #004085;
  background-color: #cce5ff;
   border-color: #b8daff;
}

.banner-close {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Arial, Baskerville, monospace;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 border: 0;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.banner-close::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.banner-close:hover,
.banner-close:focus,
.banner-close:active,
.banner-close:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Arial, Baskerville, monospace;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}
.banner-close:active {
  top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: What libraries are you using?
And show us more code.

Comment: I have added the css and javascript code as well. I'm using the jquery library for this.

Comment: I don't see your `.banner-hide` css?  And what is up with your variable `var add - banner = $('#alert-banner');`?

Comment: where is the html for the button?  I also don't see any html with the `banner-close` class.  Please include all of the relevant code to reproduce the problem.  Post it all here and in a [jsFiddle such as this.](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/0t685wzh/29/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the missing elements to your question as suggested in the comments.  I don't know what is going on with your variables, but there is a much simpler way to do what you want.  I took the liberty to add the html for a button and used the css you have there.  You can see it work in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/0t685wzh/37/). As you can see the lorem ipsum content is pushed down.

Here is my suggested js function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.banner-close').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#alert-banner").hide();
  });
});
```

This is how I modified the HTML for test purpose:

```
<div id="alert-banner" class="banner banner-top alert-primary" role="banner">
  <div class="p-4 align-self-end" style="max-width:30em">
    <h1 class="pb-4">Help us wake up to a 2020 that changes the way we see vision loss!</h1>
    <div class="text-center text-md-left"><a class="btn btn-donate text-center" style="min-width: 14em;" href="https://secure.everyaction.com/">Make a Donation</a>
    </div>
  <div>
  <button type="button" class="banner-close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">&times;</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: Can I use the 
<button type="button" class="banner-close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">&times;</button>
Instead of this?
<a href="" class="banner-close">Close the Banner</a>
Thanks, Fasih!